# Having trouble with audio through the 3.5mm jack on the Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: audio

I'm running Raspbian on the RPi2. I have the video out through HDMI and I have my speaker system plugged into the 3.5mm jack, but no sound is coming out. Sort of.

I set it to come out of the jack with

```
# amixer cset numid=3 1
```

and when I do a speaker test like this

```
# speaker-test -t sine -f 440 -c 2 -s 1
```

a tone does play through the speakers. But there's no audio when I do anything else like play Minecraft.

I have a little bit of CS experience, but I'm pretty much a beginner. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried changing settings in `raspi-config` and that didn't work. I tried setting `hdmi_drive=2` in `config.txt` but now my monitor won't display anything after the logo screen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get any sound either when I play Minecraft. I would recommend trying something like playing a song or watching a youtube video (on iceweasel, for example). Also, have you tried setting the audio out through raspi-config or testing the audio with headphones?